# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields image is showing h and it's not showing in front end

Tags: php, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

My image and alt was working fine before but I just noticed my images and alt is not showing and it's showing "h". I didn't change anything. My backend is showing the image. I'm wondering why is not working.

[image: backend image]

[image: front end code showing h and image and alt is not showing]

This is the code:

```php
$cat = get_query_var('Category');

$args = array(
  'child_of' => $cat,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);

$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) { 
  $image = get_field('cat_thumbnail_image', 'category_'. $category->term_id .'');

  echo '<article class="work-wrap">
  <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" class="work-img">
    <img src="' . $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] . '">
    <h2>'. $category->name . '</h2>
  </a>
  </article>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that extra character at the end of `get_field`. Also you need to retrieve your image in a different format, like this `$image['sizes']['thumbnail']`.  You will look inside the `sizes` array and choose your desired size.

For example, you could try the following code which will return the thumbnail of your image:

```php
$cat = get_query_var('Category');
$args = array(
    'child_of' => $cat,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) { 
    $image = get_field('cat_thumbnail_image', 'category_'. $category->term_id);

    echo '<article class="work-wrap">
    <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" class="work-img">
        <img src="' . $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] . '">
        <h2>'. $category->name . '</h2>
    </a>
</article>';
}
```